# Расширения класса C#

Tags: c#, расширения

В C# есть методы расширения. А можно ли написать Property - расширение?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пишет Эрик Липперт: [Почему нет свойств расширения?](https://web.archive.org/web/20140512033841/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ruericlippert/archive/2009/10/05/9912687.aspx).

Comment: Может есть возможность скопипастить сюда основные тезисы?